# How to handle the often-generated messages?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have the following system:

```
producer --->  proxy ---> consumer
    <good>     10 msg/s
```

A `producer` that generates messages - `10 msg/second`. A `proxy` that returns `bool` value to a `consumer` depends on how many messages producer generated, if it generate more than `10`, proxy returns `false`.

This is `timestamp`:

0.1 
0.2
0.25
0.26
0.27
0.28
0.29
0.30
0.31
0.32
0.33
0.34
2.0
2.1
2.2

Messages that comes at 0.1,  0.2,  0.25 ... 0.32 they are `good` and we return `true`, 0.32 is bad because it's 11th message in 1 second, so we return `false`.

Here is a protoype:

```
bool shouldProxyAcceptMessage(float timestamp)
```

How can I implement this algorithm?

Comment: When would you start returning `true` again?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I adapted the solution based on the OP's comments. The algorithm uses two global variables, `nrMessages` and `startTime`, and it initializes `startTime` to the current time whenever `nrMessage==0` (i.e. when it receives the first message); it returns true for the first 10 timestamps that arrived within 1 second. Once it receives a timestamp older than 1 second, it resets `nrMessages=0` (so `startTime` will reinitialize when the next timestamp arrives).

An implicit assumption we're

```
long nrMessages = 0; // global variable
long startTime = 0;
boolean shouldProxyAcceptMessage(long timestamp) {
    if (nrMessages++ == 0) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()();
    }
    timeDiff = timestamp-startTime;
    if (timeDiff > 1000) {
        nrMessages = 0;
        return false;
    } else {
        return nrMessages <= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anatoly, would it suffice to remember the time the first message was generated?

Comment: @Anatoly I now return true only for the first 10 timestamps within one second. Is that what you intended?

Comment: What about situation when `timestamp == 2.0` or bigger that `1.0`?

Comment: When first second finished, and we must to update `nrMessages`

Comment: What do you mean by  `if (timeDiff > 1 second) {` ?